# Concise way of writing $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $x\mapsto 2x$

Tags: functions, notation

I would normally see a function like this written as

$f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$

$x\mapsto 2x$

or as $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ defined by $f(x)=2x$.

Is it 'correct' (or at least, standard) to write

$f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$: $x\mapsto 2x$

Comment: It varies. I think the goal should be unambiguous :-).

Answer (score 4):

Well, I haven't seen that last notation before, but it surely is understandable. I would replace the last colon with a comma, as in

$$f\ \colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z},\ x\mapsto 2x.$$